# How to share code from one project to another and control what will be compiled to the JAR file?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a cross-project library that allows me to have a common code on a project and replicate it on other projects where I want to use that cross-project library code.

I'm programming a software plugin, that I need to export as a "JAR File" with that cross-project library packages inside, but NOT the rest of the dependencies.

Is there any better way? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need versioning of that code? Meaning, one project uses an older stable version of the package while you develop a newer one.
If you need versioning of the code in that package you should use something like Maven modules: a module representing your common package other modules representing your projects that use that code that would reference the first one.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know about Maven at that time... 

Answer (score 2):

Right-click -> Build Path -> Link Source

[image]

The better way is to just make the other project a dependency and put it on the classpath.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to include it when Export as JAR File?

Comment: @xXNurioXx if you export as runnable jar you get the option to include all dependencies.

Comment: i don't want to include all dependencies, just the linked project. Is possible with your method?

Comment: @xXNurioXx No it's not that fine grained (why don't you look at the mentioned wizard yourself?!)